# Can't get crypt to work correctly

Tags: python, crypt

I was just messing around seeing if I could use the 'crypt' module and I've seem to run into a problem that I can't for the life of me figure out. The output after I run this is this:

```
Password Not Found. secret HXXxJi0n6Huro HXXxJi0n6Huro
```

Which means that cryptWord and cryptPass are the same, so why isn't the program doing the (`if cryptWord == cryptPass:`), and `print 'Found Password:`

I just don't at all get it.

The dictionary.txt file just has the word secret in it multiple times, all on separate lines. And the evil.txt file has this line it:

```
test_user:HXXxJi0n6Huro
```

From what I can tell everything is working correctly? But something is holding this back from working right and I just can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import crypt

def testPass(cryptPass):

        salt = cryptPass[0:2]
        dictFile = open('dictionary.txt', 'r')
        for word in dictFile.readlines():
            word = word.strip('\n')
            cryptWord = crypt.crypt(word, salt)
            if cryptWord == cryptPass:
                print "[+] Found Password: "+word+"\n"
                return
        print "[-] Password Not Found. " +word,  cryptWord,  cryptPass+  "\n"
        return


def main():

    passFile= open('evil.txt')
    for line in passFile.readlines():
        if ":" in line:
            user = line.split(':')[0]
            cryptPass = line.split(':')[1]
            print "[*] Cracking Password For: "+user
            testPass(cryptPass)
if __name__ == '__main__':

        main()
```

Comment: Please do *not* add `[SOLVED]` to question titles; that's what the 'accepted answer' mark is for. :-)

Comment: Not a problem, but why did you remove the 'accepted answer' mark too? You can leave that in! :-) That's what I was trying to say, mark an answer as accepted, that's what it is there for. But you should not add `[SOLVED]` to your question title.

Comment: See [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `crypPass` value still has a newline attached to it. Strip it first:

```
user, cryptPass = line.split(':')
cryptPass = cryptPass.strip()
```

Comment: If I had reputation I'd vote you up. But thank you, it worked immediately after I added that line.

Comment: I definitely will! You answered it so quickly though that I have to wait a few minutes lol.